# Why is this command that is in my PATH not being found?

Tags: command-line, mythbuntu, error-handling

I am trying to run a command from within my MythTV interface on my Mythbuntu computer.

It won't run, and I found this error in my mythbackend.log:

```
Jul 19 15:55:47 mythbuntu mythbackend[1863]: W SystemEvent mythsystemevent.cpp:55 (run) MythSystemEventHandler: Command '/bin/sh /home/mythbuntu/Buttons/powerbutton.sh' returned 127
```

I looked up what `returned 127` means on Google, and it seems to mean simply "command not found".

But, `/bin` is on my path...

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/mythbuntu/Buttons:/home/mythbuntu
```

... and sh is definitely in there:

```
$ ls /bin/sh
/bin/sh
```

So why is this command not being found?

Comment: Have you looked at the script itself to find out whether it's exiting with that code?

Comment: @ScottSeverance: When I run the command directly from a command prompt, it executes perfectly. I assume that means the script is not at fault, and the problems are with what user runs the script, or how that script is accessed.

Comment: You could try inserting `set +x` at the beginning of powerbutton.sh. This will cause the shell to print every line of the script as it's executed. That way, you can watch it and hopefully see what's going on. If your calling script is also a shell script, you can try the same thing with it, too. Or, if it's in another language, try running it in a debugger so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The MythTV backend doesn't have access to X, so it won't be able to run things like xset without setting the environment up properly first. The instructions [here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Setting_A_Button_On_Your_Remote_To_Restart_mythfrontend) are for restarting the frontend via a script that runs via irexec, but it should be easy enough to follow and insert your poweroff script in there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, neither moving the script to `/var/lib/mythtv` nor `/usr/local/bin` worked.

Comment: what if you `sudo su mythtv` then run the script?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion too. Unfortunately, that also did not change anything.

Comment: Exactly, you are running it from the command line as the mythtv user, meaning that for some reason, that user cannot access it. What error message happens when you try that.

Comment: When I run the script from the command line, it works perfectly, whether I do it as root, or as a regular user. There is only one user account on the system, named `mythbuntu`.

Comment: Actually there is a mythtv user on the system to. Are you saying when you su to the mythtv user and run the script that it works?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a little confused with all the different users. And I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "su to the mythtv user". I know how to run commands using `sudo`, but I don't know how to "su to" a user.

Comment: do `sudo su mythtv`, then run the script

Comment: Okay, I did that, and it returned a bunch of errors. I put them here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1102005/

Comment: Ok, can you pastebin what is in that powerbutton.sh script?

Comment: Sure: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1102031/ :)

Comment: Ok, when you are the mythtv user (via sudo su mythtv), what is your PATH?

Comment: The path for the mythtv user is: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`.

Comment: odd. Ok, lets take it one command at a time (all while logged into as the mythtv user) What happens if you do `xset -q`

Comment: It says `xset:  unable to open display "localhost:11.0"`.

Comment: I ran this by another Mythbuntu dev and he saw the light I was missing. The backend doesn't have access to X, so in order to get that to work, you would need to setup the environment properly. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but it's likely better achieved with irexec (which does run in X).

Comment: Sorry... I guess I missed you in chat. What I'm trying to do is outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158630/why-is-this-custom-key-command-not-working-in-mythbuntu. Isn't irexec a utility for infra red remotes? I don't have one of those anymore.